# Saving form results to a CSV - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, csv

I'm trying to save the results of a survey to a csv file, so every time the survey is completed it adds a new line to the file. I have code that exports database rows to a csv and lets you download it, but i don't know how to incorporate saving the survey to begin with, or if this is even possible? I have a csv file set up with the correct headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your `create` function is called (the action in controller where form’s submit is directed to; create on REST controllers), you can just add some custom logic to there to convert the data from form into csv structure you want.

Ruby has [CSV](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) module builtin, which can be used to both read and write CSV files.

So you want something like following

```
require "csv"


CSV.open "output.csv", "a+" do |csv|
    # example logic from another script how to populate the file
    times.each do |key, value|
        csv << [ key, value ]
    end
end
```

You just need to define structure of rows how you want, this example throws two columns per row.

EDIT: a+ makes file to be written from the end (new rows) rather than original w+ that truncates the files.

Comment: i think this is what i was looking for! instead of key & value do i need to put the parameters of the form or something?

Comment: I added little comment to make it easier to understand. You can add any custom logic you want to inside that CSV.open block. I just have a simple loop that deconstructs the array I have and writes values from it to the csv file.

Comment: that's all i need, so do i need to create an array where you put the comment, that holds all the information from the form?

Comment: And remove the times block, naturally. Please see CSV module’s documentation for more of how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution could be to use a logger. In your application controller:

```
def surveys
  @@surveys_log ||= Logger.new("#{Rails.root}/log/surveys.log")
end
```

Anywhere where you would like to log the survey:

```
surveys.info @survey.to_csv # you'll need to implement "to_csv" yourself
```

Which will result in a `surveys.log` in your `log/` folder.